# Powershell does not run properly from a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I tried looking everywhere, reading all kinds of posts but nothing so far that could help me, so here it goes:

I am currently trying to provision a Tenant inside our multi tenant lync 2013 environment. I have my script and it does what it needs to do, when run from the Powershell ISE, however I need to be able to start the script from a batch file.
So far so good right? 
And here is the bad part.. It doesnt work and I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type

'Microsoft.Rtc.Management.WritableConfig.Settings.SimpleUrl.SimpleUrl' to type

'Microsoft.Rtc.Management.WritableConfig.Settings.SimpleUrl.Hosted.SimpleUrl'.


 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-CsSimpleUrlConfiguration]

   , InvalidCastException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException,Microsoft.Rtc.Manage
       ment.Internal.SetHostedSimpleUrlConfigurationCmdlet
+ PSComputerName        : XX-REAL
`
```

My batch file looks like this:`powershell "C:\scripts\Create_Tenant_CSV.ps1"`
As for my script it is kinda long but here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm6gpe68fuuhhd9/Create_tenant_CSV.ps1?dl=0

I had to post it in a dropbox because it doesnt get formated properly.

If someone could spot the retarded mistake i am making i would be so thankful.

Regards!

UPDATE: No matter what I try it comes down to line 117 where it says Unable to cast object... 
and i have no idea why is that

Comment: Your OS is x86 or x64? Who start your batch file? Is it started in x86 or x64 `cmd.exe` process?

Comment: x64. I have multiple ps scripts that are started using a batch file on the same machine but the problem is with this script in particular.

Comment: Would it make any difference to save the file as a [Batch + PowerShell hybrid script](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45095#p45095)?  That could circumvent any problems resulting from execution policy.  If not, then would it help to run the script in a single-threaded apartment using the `-STA` powershell command line switch?

Comment: I'll have to check about the hybrid part, however the execution policy is not an issue. Everything is being executed, the issue is one like that for some reason does not work properly.

Comment: Could also be a version issue, like maybe you have multiple versions of PowerShell installed on your system.  The ISE is executing within the context of PowerShell 4 or 5, whereas powershell.exe invoked from a batch script is executing from version 2.  You could try `powershell.exe -version 5 "C:\Scripts\Create_Tenant_CSV.ps1"` (or `-version 4` if more appropriate) and see whether that makes a difference.  I've noticed that some .NET objects are more readily recast in version 5 than in version 2.